# Loading items for an eCommerce site

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, iterator, firebase

I am attempting to make an eCommerce site from scratch. Right now I have the following code that gets all the items from a Firebase Firestore database and then adds HTML into an items div element based on the item's info.

```
var items = [];
var itemsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("items")[0];

db.collection("items").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        var docData = doc.data();
        items.push(docData);
    });
    renderItems();
});

function renderItems() {
  console.log(items);
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    itemsDiv.innerHTML += `
    <div class="item">
      <img class="itemImgBackground" src="assets/${item.name.replace(" ", "")}.png">
      <img class="itemImg" src="assets/${item.name.replace(" ", "")}.png">
      <span class="itemName">${item.name}</span>
      <span class="itemCondition">${item.condition}</span>
      <span class="itemPrice">${item.price}</span>
    </div>
    `
  });
}
```

What can I do to make my code better?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few things:

- good you're using `` ` `` (template literals) to format your HTML inside the JavaScript code
- don't use `innerHTML +=` as it forces the browser to re-render the DOM when called. Read more here: [Why is `Element.innerHTML +=` bad code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515383/why-is-element-innerhtml-bad-code). Instead create an HTML element with [`.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and append it to an existing DOM element [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

  So instead of appending the the HTML string `<div class="item">...</div>` to the parent div you can:

  1. create a wrapping `div` element:

     ```
     const div = document.createElement('div');
     ```
  2. append the HTML string to the div wrapper (remember `div` is an object of type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) but it's not already rendered in the page DOM). You can use all of Element's methods on it, including `.innerHTML`:

     ```
     div.innerHTML = `
       <div class="item">
         ...
       </div>
     `;
     ```
  3. then append the wrapper's first child to the parent element:

     ```
     divParent.appendChild(div);
     ```
- you can use [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of `.getELementByClassName`. The former allows you to pass in an actual CSS selector instead of a className (the latter method). In your case you only want the first matching element, so use [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead.
- I always use single quotes `'` for JavaScript strings and double quotes `"` when I need quotes inside the strings e.g. with HTML attributes. That's personal preference though.
- no need to define the variable `docData` as `doc.data()` is already pretty self-explanatory
- you can use arrow functions outside also `(arg1, arg2, ...) => {}` or if you have a single argument `arg => {}` (no need for the parenthesis).
- you could use `const` for constant variable to make sure they don't get their values changed: for instance `itemsDiv` (fyi: renamed to `itemsParent` for clarity) can be defined with `const` instead of `var`.

---

Here's a possible refactoring of your code:

```js
const itemsParent = document.querySelector('.items')[0];
let items = [];

const renderItems = items => {

  items.forEach(item => {

    const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = `
      <div class="item">
        <img class="itemImgBackground" src="assets/${item.name.replace(" ", "")}.png">
        <img class="itemImg" src="assets/${item.name.replace(" ", "")}.png">
        <span class="itemName">${item.name}</span>
        <span class="itemCondition">${item.condition}</span>
        <span class="itemPrice">${item.price}</span>
      </div>
    `.trim();

    itemsParent.appendChild(div.firstChild);

  });
}

db.collection('items').get().then((querySnapshot) => {

  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    items.push(doc.data());
  });

  renderItems(items);

});
```

---

**Edit:** testing div creation, it appears you need to trim the string first:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
`.trim();

console.log(div.outerHTML)
console.log(div.firstChild.outerHTML)
```

Comment: The code doesn't work, it happens when you append `div.firstChild`

Comment: For some reason, `div.firstChild` returns an object. Removing `<div class="item"` and adding `div.className = 'item'` after creating the div fixes the problem.

Comment: @JordanBaron I have corrected my answer: you first need to trim the string otherwise it won't work. Try again my code snippet to see if it works.

Comment: "_you can use `.querySelectorAll` instead of `.getELementByClassName`_" but [the latter is more than twice as fast](https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selector-performance/)...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what I mentioned in [my review of your other Post: *Carousel in Vanilla JavaScript*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/226006/120114), if there is only one element that has class *items* then it would be more appropriate to use an [**id**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute and query the DOM using [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

---

As Ivan mentioned, when defining an arrow functions: 
"Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax)</sup>

so instead of:

> ```
>  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
> ```

The parentheses around `doc` can be removed:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
```

---

The callback function that takes each element from the `querySnapshot` pushes the result from calling `.data()` into `items`.

> ```
> querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
>     var docData = doc.data();
>     items.push(docData);
> });
> ```

This can be simplified using the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
items = querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data());
```

If you do that, you could declare `items` as a `const` and pass it as an argument to `renderItems()` instead of declaring it at the top of the script.